# Swiper - Is there any way to auto scrollTop after each slide?

Tags: css, html, swiper.js

Im using swiper for some content(text, photos, videos) navigation, each slide have different height so I set autoHeight: true,

The problem is, that if I'm on the bottom of one slide and I swipe to the next, the scroll bar keeps on the bottom of the next/previous slide.

So what I need is to auto scroll to top after every slide, on either direction, next or previous

Heres a [live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/zpcxo0ja/)

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        autoHeight: true, //enable auto height
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
        keyboard: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in the docs that match what you're asking. And without a full working example, it's hard to help, but Swiper does have any number of events you can listen for.

The one you probably want is this:

```
mySwiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  // write your own scroll to top of slide function here
});
```

If you can post a live example, I will try to help further.

Comment: Live example added to the original question, if you go to slide 3 and scroll to the bottom and then slide again to the next one (slide4) it would stay on the bottom of slide 4, thats the problem ! What I need is that every time I swipe left or right go to the top of each slide.